# How do I know whether my router is VPN enabled

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I have a [TP Link router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR740N.html) and I need to create a VPN. In the admin page, at the VPN section, all three (PPTP, L2TP, IPSec ) are enabled. Does that mean I have a VPN. I am sorry if this is a noob question but I really need to know and your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have a VPN yet.  Those settings are for "VPN passthrough" which essentially means the router supports having a VPN server supporting those protocols sitting behind the router.

Your specific router does not have a VPN server built in.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the short and detailed answer.